# git push --receive-pack option and security: how to prevent from hacking?

Tags: git

`git push --receive-pack` option gives the flexibility of running `git-receive-pack` not in `$PATH`.

But it is also a security vulnerability, as it can run any other commands as well.

How can I prevent a user from hacking the server by specifying `--receive-pack`?

Similarly, how can I avoid the vulnerability from `git pull --upload-pack`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through https or ssh, you can add an authorization layer like **[gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/index.html#what)** between your git request (push/pull) and git itself.
For ssh, it will use the [ssh forced-command mechanism](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858) to intercept all commands, rejecting non-git ones.

Its [`gitolite-shell` will parse the command](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/gitolite-shell#L139-L165), and extract the repo name, calling `git-upload-pack|git-receive-pack` without taking into account the Path to the git-receive-pack program.